# Prove $V(x)$ is an increasing function (involving PDF and CDF)

Tags: probability, derivatives

I need to prove the following:

$V(x) = x + G(x)/g(x)$ is an increasing function where $G(x)$ is a CDF and $g(x)$ is the corresponding pdf.

When I take the derivative, I get

$$1 + g(x)^2/g(x)^2 - G(x)g'(x)/g(x)^2=2 - G(x)g'(x)/g(x)^2$$

How can I show that $G(x)g'(x)/g(x)^2$ is less than $2$?

Thanks

Comment: Where is this from? And what assumptions do you have on $g$ -- for instance, why can you assume it is differentiable in the first place?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Hi
Sorry everyone.  In the problem, it was assumed (from a previous part) that it is differential and g'(x) is strictly negative.  So it is obvious now.  Hopefully I didn't waste anyone's time.